# Encode string in Android so PHP would be able to gzdecompress it?

Tags: php, android, gzip

How do I correctly compress a string, so PHP would be able to decompress?

I tried this:

```
public static byte[] compress(String string) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(string.length());
    DeflaterOutputStream gos = new DeflaterOutputStream(os);
    // ALSO TRIED GZOutputStream, same results!
    gos.write(string.getBytes());
    gos.close();
    byte[] compressed = os.toByteArray();
    os.close();
    return compressed;
}
```

But PHP does not recognize output as valid GZip compressed string...

The problem seems to be in some headers / footers being added by Android...

For example when I compress `something` word via PHP with `gzcompress` I got similar results as with Android, but not similar enough, so PHP could read it:

**`something` (HEX DUMP):**

**Android**: *1f8b0800000000000000*`2bcecf4d2dc9c8cc4b0700`*fb31da0909000000*

**PHP**: *789c*`2bcecf4d2dc9c8cc4b0700`*134703cf*

The weirdest thing is that by changing `GZOutputStream` to `DeflaterOutputStream` it fixed the problem with `something` word, but the problem still appears with longer strings...

PS. Removing heading 10 characters from Android generated data does not help at all.

---

**EDIT**: I tried to decompress it in PHP with:

- `gzdecode()` - this function does not exist in standard Debian PHP5
  version.
- `gzdecompress()` - does not work

And some functions to emulate `gzdecode()` from PHP site comments that don't really do much.

All above, with removing first 10 bytes and leaving them.

PS2. I tried every single solution from Stack Overflow, and other sources, and still nothing. It is not a duplicate.

---

**EDIT2 (BINARY DUMP)**: Sample data generated with Android that can't be decomprssed by `gzuncompress()` or `pseudo-gzdecode()` functions from `PHP.NET`: [data.compressed](http://creation.pl/data.compressed).

It supposed to be some JSON, after decompression.

Comment: The comments here were getting a little "heated" so I removed them. If you can't be civil, don't post.

Comment: I am replacing my hex comment after all of the comments were summarily deleted: your hex dump was missing all leading zeros.  You need to print two hex digits per byte, otherwise a string of hex digits is ambiguous.  I edited your question to fix the hex dumps.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now what is the problem with hex. Miracle of coffee. I linked binary dump in `EDIT2`.

Comment: Is it possible that you're compressing the data manually, and then sending it to the server via a method that compresses it automatically by default, e.g. HttpURLConnection, or similar?

Comment: Seems that was the problem, double compression. Please add this comment to your answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I think it's @MarkAdler that you want to have add this to his answer. Out of interest, what was doing the second compression?

Comment: The http client itself... when we set `Content-Encoding` to `gzip`, and, yes I did mistake You with Mark, sorry... of course, Your comment was correct, so I could accept it, if You would rewrite it to answer.

Comment: The double compression already is in my answer.  Has been since shortly after EDIT2 provided the actual data.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't notice, sorry. Accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android data that starts with `1f8b` is a gzip stream.  In php you use `gzdecode()` for that.  `gzencode()` on php makes gzip streams.

The php data that starts with `789c` is a zlib stream.  You used `gzcompress()` to make that, and you would use `gzuncompress()` to decode it.

The compressed data contained within both of those streams, starting with `2bce` is raw deflate data.  You can use `gzinflate()` to decode that if you happened to make it somewhere, and you can use `gzdeflate()` to generate raw deflate.

Just to rant, `gzencode()`, `gzcompress()`, and `gzdeflate()` are some of the most misleading function names ever concocted, since only one of them is related to gzip yet all start with `gz`, and nothing in the name `gzcompress()` indicates zlib.

*Update:*

The "EDIT2" data is, for some reason, doubly compressed.  It was compressed first to the zlib format, and then that zlib stream was compressed to the gzip format.  (Though gzip couldn't compress the already compressed data, so it's a little bigger.)

You should repair the problem that made it doubly compressed.  Or if you have no control over that, you can doubly decompress it, first stripping the gzip header using the RFC 1952 specification and then `gzinflate()` on the raw deflate data, and then using `gzdecompress()` on the result.

Comment: `gzdecode()` function is not available in most PHP (non windows) versions, and as you probably didn't notice, I don't use `GZOutputStream`, but `DeflaterOutputStream`. Anyway... still got no solution.

Comment: Then you can manually decode the gzip header using the information in RFC 1952, and then `gzinflate()` on the raw deflate data.  (Just removing the first ten bytes may or may not work, since the header can be longer than ten bytes depending on the content.)

Comment: If you are generating a zlib stream, then `gzdecompress()` will work on that.  If you have a problem with larger streams, then the data is being corrupted somewhere along the way by some other bug.

Comment: I am not rude, just tired... tried like 100000 ways from different solutions, and still nothing... Sorry if you felt that way. `gzinflate()` doesn't work, no matter if I remove first 10 bytes or not. The data is not corrupted. I checked that out.

Comment: Then provide an example of the data you cannot decode.  (Correctly converting to hex.)  I predict that either a) the data can be decoded, or b) it is corrupted..

Comment: Please check EDIT2 (bottom of question) for sample data. Thank you for your time. `+1`